# Panel data splitting

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to split my data as train and test set to run the LTSM. There are several countries under ID column and I am splitting the data according to date interval as seen below. My intention is to split the data for specific time interval for each of the countries. But I got the error, which only states

```
KeyError: False

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

Here my codes:

```
def train_test_split(data):
    mask1 = (data['Date'] >= '2020-04') & (data['Date'] <= '2020-05')
    test=data.loc[mask1]
    mask2 = (data['Date'] >= '2014-01') & (data['Date'] <= '2020-03')
    train=data.loc[mask2]
    y_train=train.IndustrialP
    x_train=train.drop('IndustrialP', axis=1)
    y_test=test.IndustrialP
    x_test=test.drop('IndustrialP', axis=1)
    return x_train, x_test,y_train,y_test
```

worked till here.

```
# loop each station and collect train and test data 
X_train=[]
X_test=[]
Y_train=[]
Y_test=[]
for i in range(0,len(ID)):
    df=data[['ID']==ID[i]]
    x_train, x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(df)
    X_train.append(x_train)
    X_test.append(x_test)
    Y_train.append(y_train)
    Y_test.append(y_test)
```

got error above. Also intented to run the following codes:

```
# concat each train data from each station 
X_train=pd.concat(X_train)
Y_train=pd.DataFrame(pd.concat(Y_train))
# concat each test data from each station 
X_test=pd.concat(X_test)
Y_test=pd.DataFrame(pd.concat(Y_test))
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide the entire traceback? `KeyError: False` indicate that somewhere in your code, some 'key' doesn't exist in the set, so its posible that the error it's in for loop or train_test_split

Comment: `KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2896             try:
-> 2897                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2898             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()`

Comment: `KeyError: False

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-e144880b4fd8> in <module>
      5 Y_test=[]
      6 for i in range(0,len(ID)):
----> 7     df=data[['ID']==ID[i]]
      8     x_train, x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(df, df["ID"])
      9     X_train.append(x_train)`

Comment: `/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2993             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2994                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2995             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2996             if is_integer(indexer):
   2997                 indexer = [indexer]`

Comment: `/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2897                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2898             except KeyError:
-> 2899                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2900         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2901         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:`

Comment: `pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: False`

Comment: Sorry about sharing the traceback like that, SO does not allow to write long comments, that is why I had to split.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

`df=data[['ID']==ID[i]]` to `df=data[data['ID']==ID[i]]`